# After Update Woocommerce Version 3.2.1 getting error

Tags: woocommerce

After Update Woocommerce Version 3.2.1 getting error on admin woocommerce settings section. The error is "Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in \woocommerce\includes\admin\settings\class-wc-settings-general.php on line 29"

but on front end no error on cart page and check out page.

So someone please help me how can i fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the same files and replace it with ftp.

```
lass-wc-settings-general.php
```

From the official git repository: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/includes/admin/settings

Thats may help you.